# HoloLens 2 / Unity / App Lifecycle : Handling Resuming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, lifecycle, hololens

When a HoloLens 2 app is closed by the user it will go into a Suspended state as per the [Documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-model), I would like to perform some actions such as checking the network connectivity when the app is Resumed.

How can this be handled or detected? is there an event that is triggered when the app is Resumed?

In a normal UWP I could do something like:

```
partial class MainPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.Current.Resuming += new EventHandler<Object>(App_Resuming);
   }

    private void App_Resuming(Object sender, Object e)
    {
        // TODO: Do Something
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't get the Windows CoreApplication.Resuming method to work I have been looking at Unity methods as an alternative.

The one I found that did what I needed was [OnApplicationFocus](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html).

On the application being suspended OnApplicationFocus will have the focus parameter set to false. On the application being resumed the focus parameter will be set to true.

I dont beleive that this is triggered on first app load.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
    
    }
}
```

Just to be clear my preference is the Windows method if there is a way to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done still.  Just need to add this into a Start method.

```
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
  using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel;  
  using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
#endif
```

Example that can be added into your main GameObject:

```
    void Start()
    {
       #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
          CoreApplication.Resuming += this.OnResuming;  
       #endif
    }

    #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
    private void OnResuming(object sender, object args)  
    {  
       //your custom code on resuming
    }  
    #endif
```

Comment: Hello Nathan, sorry for the delay. Having just tried this it seems like I need to add a reference to something. Do you know what I need to reference to allow me to use Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel?

Comment: Hi @tfcmad, usually you just put the using Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel in the section of #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT, and there is no extra reference for it. Do you have any errors when building the project? Please note that Unity doesn't support executing WinRT API in Editor.

Comment: Hello @Seth DU - MSFT, I've added the code wrapped as shown. But I get the build error: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?). I get this when building onto the Hololens 2.

Comment: It's just "Windows.ApplicationModel". There's no "Microsoft." in front. That should fix that error you're getting.

Comment: Hello Sunius, I think you're correct, when I use "Windows.ApplicationModel", I don't get any reference errors. It will now register the event in Start() without an error, however the event doesn't fire when resuming the app, however OnApplicationFocus does.